# Hard Drive Info

Tags: hard-drive

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my laptop about a month ago. The laptop has a 500Gb HD (483.9 actually shows up). I’ve applied all the updates (security, etc.), and as of today, I can no longer install updates. In searching for a way to make room, I’ve noticed that I cannot get any usable information on the HD, as I can with Mac and Windows. I cannot see how much of the HD is used, and how much is unused. Also, I cannot see how many backups have been archived (I’d like to remove the oldest ones to make room). What am I to do?

Comment: I am not sure I can help you fully, but try with opening up a terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type `df -h`. There you can see how much space there really is free on your hard drive. If that is not enough you can use the command
`sudo du -hs /*`. This makes you see where the space is eaten up.
Then, just go down the trees from there.

Comment: What you should do depends on what you want. You list some issues but give no hint about what you want to achieve regarding them. Could please [edit] your question to clarify that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `gnome-disk-utility`.  You can run this from the command line or look for `Disks` using the HUD.  It should give you information of of all the mounted disks and how full they are.  There are text-based utilities as well but this should do.

Now, to analyse what is taking most of the space, you can use `Disk usage analyzer`.

Comment: I was just reading up on gnome disks for SSD support: https://www.linux.com/learn/how-test-solid-state-drive-health-gnome-disks